# iPhone App Built on Amazon Web Services

Tags: database, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, user-management

I am building an iPhone app that stores user logon credentials in an AWS DynamoDB.  In another DynamoDB I am storing locations of files (stored in S3) for that user.  What I don't understand is how to make this secure.  If I use a Token Vending Machine that gives that application an ID with access to the user DynamoDB, isn't it possible that any user could access the entire DB and just add or delete any information that they desire?  They would also be able to access the entire S3 bucket using this setup.  Any recommendations on how I could set this up securely and properly?

I am new to user DB management, and any links to helpful resources would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IAM permissions are more finegrained than you think. You can allow/disallow specific API calls, so for example you might only allow read operations. You can also allow access to a specific resource only. On S3 this means that you can limit access to a specific file or folder , but dynamodb policies can only be set at the table level.

Personally I wouldn't allow users direct access to dynamodb - I'd have a webservice mediating access to that, although users being able to upload directly to s3 or download straight from s3 is a good thing (Your web service  can in general give out pre signed urls for that though)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding S3 and permissions, you may find the answer on the following question useful:

[Temporary Credentials Using AWS IAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181996/temporary-credentials-using-aws-iam/13203735#13203735)